# Crystal Reports formula to add formatting if the string is not null?

Tags: crystal-reports, report, string-formatting, phone-number

I have a secondary phone number that is not always filled out but must still appear on a report. I'm trying to make a simple formula that tests if the string is null and if not add formatting to a phone number.

I can add formatting to the phone number by using:

```
picture ({table1.PhoneNumber},"(xxx)xxx-xxxx")
```

And I know there is an "IsNull" operator but I can't really figure out the syntax to put the two statements together.

I need to do this:

If the phone number is not null then apply formatting, If it is null then make the string = "N/A"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if isnull({table1.PhoneNumber}) then
 'N/A'
else
 picture ({table1.PhoneNumber},"(xxx)xxx-xxxx")
```

Comment: Great Thanks, That seems easy enough!